# How to get the error cause of json.NewDecoder(body).Decode() when a http timeout occurs?

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the error cause while JSON decoding `http.Response.Body`

```
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&lResp); err != nil {
    // Get the cause of err
}
```

The type of `err` (and `errors.Cause(err)` using either `github.com/pkg/errors` or `github.com/friendsofgo/errors`) is `*errors.errorString`.

So what I'm able to do right now is the exact opposite of checking for the error type, namely:

```
if strings.HasSuffix(cause.Error(), "(Client.Timeout exceeded while reading body)") {
    //...
}
```

I can try to use [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) and then I'll get `*http.httpError` as an error when the timeout occurs.

The primary reason is that I don't want to get the partially read JSON structure in the error - only the cause of the error and with current way, it's being done (the error returned) I get:

```
main.ListingResponse.DataSources: struct CustomType{ /* partially read JSON struct ... */ }.net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while reading body)
```

Comment: If there's an error, don't use `lResp`. Simple as that. Only assume `lResp` to be valid / usable if `err` is `nil`.

Comment: @icza Agreed but I'd like to act upon timeouts (do a manual retry of some sort) hence my question.

Comment: Have you tried checking the error type? If you have a `net.Error` then you have a `Timeout()` method

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsTimeout

Comment: @JimB Just as I mentioned: `err` returned from `Decode()` is of type `*errors.errorString`

Comment: @Peter `os.IsTimeout()` doesn't work in this case

Comment: @Patryk: yup, missed that.  Just read the full response and unmarshal it in 2 separate steps. That way the read error isn't wrapped in the json package.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the fact that `*http.httpError` is a `net.Error`?

Comment: The decoder returns the io.Reader error as is.  Just check for net.Error timeout as suggested by JimB in his first comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up reading the response body into into a `[]byte` and then unmarshalling it with `json.Unmarshal()`

```
bb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    var netError net.Error
    if errors.As(err, &netError) {
        log.Printf("netError %v", netError)
        // handle net.Error...
        return nil, netError
    }
    // handle general errors...
    return nil, netError
}

var lResp LResponse
if err := json.Unmarshal(bb, &lResp); err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to unmarshal LResponse")
}
```

I'm still looking for a solution to use `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&str)` to avoid copying whole body into memory.

If anyone knows the way to do it, please add your answer.

Comment: What is the reason for ignoring all but net errors when slurping up the response body?

Comment: @iLoveReflection Just wanted to do a manual retry of some sorts (and some accounting for that) and I wanted to figure out a way to do that (manual error inspection as depicted).

Comment: I get that you want to retry, but that does not explain the reason for ignoring errors.  Also, it seems odd to treat net.Error differently from other errors when reading the response body.  Why not `bb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); if err != nil { return err }`.

Comment: @iLoveReflection I might have oversimplified this. I do take care of other errors as well. Le me edit the answer