# How to close a Server-Sent Events connection to read

Tags: go, server-sent-events, go-context

I'm trying to make a test for an http endpoint that uses Server-Sent Events to give a json stream, but after cancelling the response's context.Context, my json.Decode(resp.Body) is returning a "context cancelled" error. How would I gracefully finish the request to read all of the body received? Is there something I need to do on the server side?

UPDATE:

I've made a minimal reproducible example and found you can get the body of a cancelled request, but the example is flaky and doesn't work if there's a time.Sleep after the cancel. Why is this?

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "time"
)

func Subscribe(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "streaming unsupported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    flusher.Flush()

    tick := time.Tick(500 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-req.Context().Done():
            return
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "EVENT!")
            flusher.Flush()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    s := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(Subscribe))
    defer s.Close()
    c := s.Client()

    var sub *http.Response
    var cancelSub context.CancelFunc
    {
        ctx := context.Background()
        ctx, cancelSub = context.WithCancel(ctx)
        req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, s.URL+"/subscribe", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        sub, err = c.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        defer sub.Body.Close()
        if sub.StatusCode != 200 {
            panic("StatusCode != 200")
        }
    }

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    cancelSub()

    // WITH THIS SLEEP NO BODY IS PRINTED?!
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    b, err := io.ReadAll(sub.Body)
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\nbody:\n%s\n", err, b)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/sIjaoqpCuqC

Output with the sleep:

```
error: context canceled
body:
```

Output without the sleep:

```
error: context canceled
body:
EVENT!
EVENT!
EVENT!
EVENT!
EVENT!
```

Comment: please show a minimal reproducible example of code ideally something that can execute on the go playground but at least something for us to look at

Comment: @erik258 I've added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: In my opinion, it looks a little weird that you read the body after canceling its context, because cancel can release the resources https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel. I found the body read can be different when adding other codes, besides `time.Sleep(time.Second)`

Comment: For example, this code (https://go.dev/play/p/KS3PoAKcIcY, Please run it on your IDE) do not execute `the sleep for a second` you mentioned. But it shows no body contents.

Comment: I think the resource release might be done by channel and so the body can look different depending on a timing. I think it will be better just to handle the error without reading its body.

Comment: Good to know! I hoped to conclude the request so I could check the entire body in tests, but maybe I'll just not cancel and read however many lines there should be so it shouldn't block.

Answer (score 0):

## In summary

- I think it is natural that the cancel, timeout, deadline from context can happen when reading the response body. (https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext)
- In my opinion, the best is to handle the error by context and the error by json separately, or extend the deadline/timeout (if you use it with context)

## In detail

In my opinion, it is natural that the `cancel, timeout, deadline` from `context` can happen when reading the response body.

> For an outgoing client request, the context controls the entire lifetime of a request and its response: obtaining a connection, sending the request, and reading the response headers and body.
> https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext

So if you want to avoid the `cancel, timeout, deadline` by context, I think you should extend the value of it like

```golang
...
    enoughLongTime = time.Second*10

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), enoughLongTime)
    defer cancel()

    req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)
...
```

But if you want to differentiate the `cancel, timeout, deadline` and handling json, I think you can try this.

```golang
respBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    var netError net.Error
    if errors.As(err, &netError) {
        log.Printf("netError %v", netError)
        return nil, netError
    }
    return nil, netError
}

var jResult JsonResult
if err := json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &jResult); err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to unmarshal jResult")
}
```

I referred the two pages

- [Go json.NewDecoder().Decode() doesn't seem to respect context deadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804689/go-json-newdecoder-decode-doesnt-seem-to-respect-context-deadline)
- [How to get the error cause of json.NewDecoder(body).Decode() when a http timeout occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731147/how-to-get-the-error-cause-of-json-newdecoderbody-decode-when-a-http-timeout)